# Negation of cardinal characteristics

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

Looking over the various cardinal characteristics of the continuum all of them are defined by a sentence of the form:

"$\mathfrak{x}$ is the *least* cardinality of a subset of $\omega^\omega$ that $\ldots$"

Is there any meaningful cardinal characteristic whose definition can be given by

"$\mathfrak{x}$ is the *supremum* of the cardinalities of subsets of $\omega^\omega$ that $\ldots$"

I tried negating the definition of the usual cardinal characteristics, e.g. $\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{d}$, but there are easy examples of size $2^{\aleph_0}$.

So, I am afraid the answer is "No", but I would be glad to hear otherwise.

Comment: What about the supremum of the cardinalities of strong-measure-zero subsets of $\mathbb R$? I don't know if you'd consider it a "cardinal characteristic" or not, especially since it is consistent that this cardinal is countable, but otherwise it fits the bill. There's a question about it here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281024/the-strong-measure-number/281041#281041.

Comment: @WillBrian: I have to see what is the strong-measure-zero subsets of R.

Comment: @WillBrian. This seems a good candidate, but is it consistent that $\mathfrak{s}_+$ is a cardinal between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: It is a theorem that $\mathfrak{s}_+$ is a cardinal between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ (inclusive). It is consistent that it is $\aleph_0$ (this happens in Laver's model -- google "Borel conjecture" to read more about it), that it is uncountable but less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ (this happens in the random real model), and that it is equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$, even when CH fails (this happens in the Cohen model).

Comment: @WillBrian. Then this answers the question! Do you mind writhing it out so I can give you some credit :)

Comment: @WillBrian. Can you give me a reference for the consistency results? I am more interested in the random reals case, where $\mathfrak{s}_+$ is strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: The results about the Cohen and random model can be found in chapter 8 of Bartoszynski and Judah's book *Set Theory: on the structure of the real line*. For the random real model, it follows from Theorem 8.2.8 that there are uncountable strong measure zero sets, and it is Theorem 8.2.11 that every strong measure zero set has size $\leq \aleph_1$.

Comment: So you don't consider the cardinal characteristic $\mathfrak c= 2^{\aleph_0}$ meaningful?

Comment: Is $\aleph_1$ a meaningful characteristic? This is the largest cardinal of a subset of the reals which carries a well-order all initial segments of which are Borel.

Comment: @Goldstern I like your characterization of $\aleph_1$, but you can not change the value of this "characteristic".